# Filtar columna en Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, filtro, apply

Tengo un dataframe `df` en el que la columna `palabras` tiene elementos que son listas.
por ejemplo:

```
df  i            palabras
    0  ["abc", "def","ghi","jkl]
    1  ["dd", "gg", "ds"]
    2  ["asd", "qwe", "sdsw", "sde"]
```

y tengo un gran array llamado `palabras_dict`, que me funciona como diccionario.

Mi objetivo es transformar `df` en uno de la siguiente forma

```
df  i            palabras           palabras_en_diccionario      palabras_not_in 
    0  ["abc", "def","ghi","jkl]         ["abc"]                ["def","ghi","jkl]
    1  ["dd", "gg", "ds"]                ["dd",  "ds"]               ["gg"]
    2  ["asd", "qwe", "sdsw", "sde"]     ["sdsw", "sde"]
```

["asd", "qwe"]

es decir, separar la columna `palabras` en dos, una con los string de `df.palabras` que se encuentren en `palabras_dict` y otro de las que no están.

Lo estoy hacienod así:

```
import swifter

df['palabras'].swifter.apply(lambda x: [_ for _ in x if _ in palabras_dict])
```

(Las otras columnas creo que las puedo hallar eficientemente con un `.apply(lambda x: list(set(x) -?? ))`
en la columna `palabras`donde `?? = set(columna palabras_en_diccionario en la fila de x)`

Pero esta linea para el primer filtro toma demasiado tiempo (7421 registros con cada fila de `palabras` con buena cantidad de elementos)

Hay alguna forma vectorizada de manera que `swifter` funcione más rápido o alguna manera de hacer el mismo ejercicio de una manera más eficiente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

### 1. Probar con map.

Puedes usar el método `map` en ocasiones puede ser más rápido. Te quedaría así:

```
df_palabras['palabras_en_diccionario'] = df_palabras['palabras'].map(lambda x: [_ for _ in x if _ in palabras_dict])
```

### 2. Usar Dask

Dask es un framework igual que Pandas, de hecho copia a Pandas, con el objetivo de poder trabajar con conjuntos de datos más grandes. Una de sus principales ventajas es que puede **trabajar en paralelo**, esto quiere decir que puede coger tu 7421 registros y crear x dataframes donde x es el número de hilos que tu tienes (o asignas) y finalizar mucho más rápido (dependiendo del número de hilos que tengas). Te quedo un ejemplo de su funcionamiento, ya que es muy parecido a Pandas, pero te recomiendo leerte su documentación [aquí.](https://dask.org/)

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

N = 8 #Número de hilos que quieres en funcionamiento esto hará que la operación vaya casí 8 veces más rápido

#Nos traemos el dataframe, de Pandas a Dask.
dd_palabras = ddf.from_pandas(df_palabras, npartitions=N)

# Para aplicar la función, usamos .compute()
dd_palabras['palabras_en_diccionario'] = dd_palabras.['palabras'].map(lambda x:[_ for _ in x if _ in palabras_dict]).compute()
```

#### Advertencias:

- En la biblioteca `multiprocesing` tienes la función `cpu_counts()` por si no sabes el número de hilos que tiene tu CPU
- En Dask las funciones no se ejecutan cuando lanzas el código, se almacenan en un grafo de operaciones, esperando a que tu le ordenes que se tienen que ejecutar, esto se conoce como **lazy evaluation** y es una de las principales virtudes de Dask, que le permite manejar grandes cantidades de datos a gran velocidad